# Tensor flow throws an uninitialized error even after the variable is initialized

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to write a program in python using tensorflow to fit data with different patterns using a neural network with a hidden layer. I am facing an error with the code which states that the variable b2 is uninitialized. But I have initialized it already and dont understand what I am missing here.

This is part of an [assignment](http://ranger.uta.edu/~kamangar/CSE-5368-FA18/Assignment05(Duedate.Nov.18,2018).html) (the dataset can be understood here) and got stuck here while solving it.

The link to the colab notebook is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1U2CtJ3-_pJUshFbnVZJjml3ooz15aIq6).

The initialization lines look like

```
W1 = tf.Variable(np.random.uniform(low=-0.01, high=0.01, size=(hidden, 2)), name="W1")
b1 = tf.Variable(np.random.uniform(low=-0.01, high=0.01, size=(hidden, 1)), name="b1")
W2 = tf.Variable(np.random.uniform(low=-0.01, high=0.01, size=(classes, hidden)), name="W2")
b2 = tf.Variable(np.random.uniform(low=-0.01, high=0.01, size=(classes, 1)), name="b2")
```

The code snippet that shows the computation graph is below.

```
operation = "ReLU" # "Sigmoid"
o = tf.add(tf.matmul(W1, p), b1)
# ReLU or Sigmoid
if operation == "ReLU":
  z = tf.zeros((hidden, 1), dtype=tf.float64)
  output = tf.maximum(o, z)
else:
  output = tf.sigmoid(o)
foutput = tf.add(tf.matmul(W2, output), b2)
crossentropy = tf.log(tf.exp(foutput) / tf.reduce_sum(tf.exp(foutput), 0))
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  ce = sess.run([crossentropy], feed_dict={p : inputs, t : targets, lr : 0.01})
print(ce)
```

Error message

```
FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333     try:
-> 1334       return fn(*args)
   1335     except errors.OpError as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1318       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1319           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1320 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1406         self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1407         run_metadata)
   1408 

FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value b2
     [[{{node b2/read}} = Identity[T=DT_DOUBLE, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](b2)]]
```

Comment: For newer tensorflow versions you should use `tf.global_variables_initializer()`. Does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to run the init function in the graph before computing cross entropy:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)
  ce = sess.run([crossentropy], feed_dict={p : inputs, t : targets, lr : 0.01})
```

Also, `tf.initialize_all_variables()` is deprecated. Use `tf.global_variables_initializer()` instead.

Comment: Thank you. This solution works for me. Does it mean that I cant initialize variables outside a session ?